# Where does the Dynamic Link point to on the activation record

Tags: programming-languages, compilers

I'm a bit confused as to wear exactly the dynamic link points to on the activation record. I understand that it points to the 'top' of the instance of the callers activation record but I am unsure of where the 'top' is.

Based on an example from my textbook:

[image]

It would appear to me that the 'top' of the calling function is spatially the bottom of the calling functions activation record.

But the problem is that a couple of pages later when it discusses the static link the example has changed where the dynamic link points to:

[image]

Now it seems to be pointing at, what I would describe as, the structural top of the callers activation record.

Does where we point to change when we are including static links? I noticed that the static links point to the structural bottom like the dynamic links used to; does that having something to do with it?